# Creating an interface that inherits from IPropertyChanged using explicit implementation

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

I was looking at [Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged - does a better way exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist), (specifically the accepted answer) and this works great for any cases where you don't need or aren't using a base class. However, I would like to implement it using another interface, taking advantage of explicit implementation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) in order to allow implementing classes to inherit from other base classes without modifying the said base class.

I tried doing something along the lines of:

```
    public interface INotifyPropertyChangedWithHelper : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        void SetProperty<T>(T value, ref T property, string propertyName)
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(property, value))
            {
                property = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            }
        }

        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

but that last line throws an error CS0079 (The event '`INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`' can only appear on the left hand side of `+=` or `-=`). I am assuming this because `PropertyChanged` can't be invoked from anywhere besides the class that implements it, but is there any way to work around this?

If the answer is "no, you have to use a base class", that's fine, but I'd love to make this work in a way that doesn't block off the use of other base classes.

Comment: This: _"but that last line fails to compile"_ is not how to ask a question.  Please include the error code and message (translated to English if necessary) whenever you say you have a compilation issue.

Comment: Apologies, changing now